# How to wait till json file loaded

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery's $.getJSON method to get two json file.

This is simple structure of my code

```
$.getJSON(url1, function(data) {
 //some code
}
$.getJSON(url2, function(data) {
 //some code
}
fillList();
```

I want that to call the fillList() method only after both the json data succesfully loaded.
What is the simplest method to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jQuery deferred object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) can help you, even i didn't test it, but try below

```
var dfd = $.Deferred();

function fn1()
{
   $.getJSON(url1, function(data) {
     //some code
  }
  $.getJSON(url2, function(data) {
   //some code
  }
}


dfd.done(fn1,fillList);
```

or there isn one example on [.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

```
var jqxhr = $.getJSON("example.json", function() {
  alert("success");
})
.success(function() { fillList(); })
```